# Why is tensorflow still not seeing my GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been confused by this issue for a few days now. I've tried reinstalling my driver and I still cant get my GPU to work with tensorflow.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 13159433722602582150
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 12266805389881928380
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 1094190154514983639
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

This seems different from what I'm expecting:

```
 [name: "/device:CPU:0"
    device_type: "CPU"
    memory_limit: 268435456
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 4549764507052008926
    , name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
    device_type: "XLA_CPU"
    memory_limit: 17179869184
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 5130440468361087955
    physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
    , name: "/device:GPU:0"
    device_type: "GPU"
    memory_limit: 3136264601
    locality {
    bus_id: 1
    links {
    }
    }
    incarnation: 8742529146709444949
    physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 
    0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
    , name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
    device_type: "XLA_GPU"
    memory_limit: 17179869184
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 12774508348529661585
    physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
    ]
    [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
>>> True
```

```
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
>>> []
```

Here's my driver details.

```
nvidia-smi
Sun Nov 29 11:34:23 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 457.30       Driver Version: 457.30       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   53C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    112MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     15232      C   ...ython\Python38\python.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Some people say the issue is with CUDA version being more than 10. Some people say the issue is that I should uninstall tensorflow and reinstall tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: Both people are highly likely to be correct. Tensorflow is very picky on version numbers. I'd suggest first installing every component in [this table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) with all version numbers **strictly aligned**. (No higher or lower versions. Absolutely no.) And then install the corresponding `tensorflow-gpu` version. Package `tensorflow` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comment you should install Tensorflow GPU version with supported `CUDA` and `CuDNN` version.

Your Cuda version is `11.1`, but in tensorflow there is no support for it in prebuilt version of `2.3.0` and before. For tensorflow 2.4.0 you can use `CUDA 11 and cuDNN 8.0.2` as seen in release notes,

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.4.0-rc3

> TensorFlow pip packages are now built with CUDA11 and cuDNN 8.0.2.

If you want to use 2.3.0 then downgrade to cuda 10.1 and cudnn 7.6.